# if number is in a section of numbers

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

Not sure how to word this. I currently have a script that I would like to be more dynamic...

```
if(endpos < 7){
$('#div').tinycarousel({start:1});
}else if(endpos>6 && endpos<13){
$('#div').tinycarousel({start:2});
}else if(endpos>12 && endpos<19){
$('#div').tinycarousel({start:3});
}else if(endpos>18 && endpos<25){
$('#div').tinycarousel({start:4});
}else{
$('#div').tinycarousel({start:5});
}
```

So this works for me now, but what if endpos = 150, I am stuck with start:5. I could keep writing the scales so they went to 1000, but it doesn't make any sense to do that. I am sure there is a way to write it one time so that the number for "start" increases by 1 for each section of 6 that "endpos" increases.

Comment: I'd also have used `>=` and `<=` in a scenario like this. Or `>=` and `<`. Easier to read! As it stands, it *looks* like there's an overlap in the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Math.ceil(endpos/6)
```

ceil will take let's say .5 and make it the next highest whole number, 1 in this case.

Comment: More specifically, he can replace that entire block with `$('#div').tinycarousel({start:Math.ceil(endpos/6)});`

Comment: @Mark, thank you. I'm on a mobile device, so typing is difficult.

Comment: @iabstractdownvotefactory All above correct! Thank you all for the help, this worked out perfect and made perfect sense. I feel a bit silly for not thinking of it, but it was just driving me nuts!

Answer (score 2):

Divide your endpos by 6, the result will be your 'start'.  For instance, if endpos is 24, start  will be 24/6 I.e. 4.  In case the result is a real number, take the ceil to get correct value.

Comment: 5/6=0.8333 but it looks like he wants to start at 1. should ceil, not floor.

Comment: @rb: Huh? 5 is the intended answer. Look at his sample. 19-24 (inclusive) is 4, so 25-30 *should* be 5.

Comment: crap, my bad  (removed my comment)!